# Placing a window to the top-left corner of a WPF control

Tags: wpf, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to place a window in a way which its top-left corner will be in the same point of a specific WPF control op-left corner.
So I tried getting the control's screen coordinates like this:

```
 PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(ctrl);
 Point posFromScreen = ctrl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
 Point targetPoints = source.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.Transform(posFromScreen);
```

and then I set the `Top` and `Left` coordinates of the window to `targetPoints`.
But My window always appears to the RIGHT of the control instead of overlapping with him in the top-left corner.

What am I doing wrong? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be sufficient to write

```
var p = ctrl.PointToScreen(new Point());
Left = p.X;
Top = p.Y;
```